# I can’t solve the scroll problem React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I can’t solve the scroll problem React Native. I’m just learning and I can’t figure out how to fix this problem. I want the flatlist to occupy the right width, and now it occupies just "100%" width without taking into account the scroll

```
return (
<View style={styles.container}>
<Image
 source={{
    uri: data.img,}}
style={styles.pizzaImg}
/>
<View
    style={{
                    height: 200,
                    marginBottom: 50,
                }}
            >
                <PizzasListItemTextBox big={true} data={data} />
            </View>

            <FlatList
                data={addToPizzaOrder}
                renderItem={({ item }) => <PizzasListItem data={item} big={true} />}
                horizontal={true}
                showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                contentContainerStyle={{
                    flexGrow: 1,
                    backgroundColor: 'blue',
                }}
            />
        </View>
    )
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        alignItems: 'center',
        paddingTop: 20,
        backgroundColor: '#f6f3f1',
    },
    pizzaImg: {
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
    },
})
```

[[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Y56l.jpg)]
[[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaajd.jpg)]

I tried to set different values and different properties of the container, but it failed

Answer (score -1):

Add `flatlist` attribute

```
style={{ width :"80%",}}
```